# Ionic 4 spinner animation

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I can seem to figure out why the ionic 4 spinners are not respecting its boundaries as it spins, I am using `android version 8.0.0`
[image]

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.11.0 (/home/yushin/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 20 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/yushin/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v11.9.0 (/home/yushin/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.8.0
   OS                : Linux 4.13
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, please create a [mcve]

Comment: Would it be possible to show the spinner code?

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: I've used ion-spinner I didn't experience the problem in UI like you do. Can you post your code?

Comment: lol no longer on ionic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same issue with the Android loader. Ideally, the CSS of the `ion-spinner` should be updated to something like:

```
:host(.spinner-crescent) svg {
    transform-origin: 40% 40%!important;
}
```

However, since Ionic 4 is now using shadow dom, you won't be able to apply that to the component from outside.

The solution I found was to go with an alternative spinner (e.g., circles).

```
let loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    message: message,
    spinner: 'circles'
});
await loading.present();
```